# handling signals in native code - with JVM crash with SIGSEGV in terminal

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, signals, native

this is my first post so please show some understanding.
 I have some java code and I have some native code.

The java part isn't so interesting at the moment so I'll skip to the c++ part:

```
//some more trivial includes
#include <signal.h>


//these are global variables
jclass GLOBAL_CLASS;
JNIEnv * GLOBAL_ENV;
jobject GLOBAL_OBJECT;
jmethodID METHOD_ID;

void sigproc(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
{
        signal(SIGINT, sigproc);
        //if Ctrl-c is pressed I want to call a method within my java class
        //since I can pass only int to this function
        //I've decided to use global variables
        GLOBAL_ENV->CallVoidMethod(GLOBAL_OBJECT, METHOD_ID);
        exit(0);
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_intern_Work_readFromFile
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray arr)
{

/*define a signal trap! */
signal(SIGINT, sigproc);
//sigproc(SIGINT);
/*initialize the global variables */
GLOBAL_ENV = env;
GLOBAL_OBJECT = obj;
GLOBAL_CLASS = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
//method id is the same so it's better to cache it
//at the beginning
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(GLOBAL_CLASS,
                                      "nativeListener", 
                                      "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
METHOD_ID = GLOBAL_ENV->GetMethodID(GLOBAL_CLASS,
                    "closeEverything", "()V");
    //let's say I have a while(true) block just below
    //and some more work is done.
}
```

This function is triggered at the start of my MainClass.
The program runs correctly if I remove

```
GLOBAL_ENV->CallVoidMethod(GLOBAL_OBJECT, METHOD_ID);
```

but the problem is that I need it because I plan to free some dynamic allocated memory + I need to call this function of my class. (in other words ... when I press ctrl-c in terminal it says JVM cheshes with SIGSEGV)

It seems I don't actually understand what really is going on when a signal is passed from the kernel. Is my global variable GLOBAL_ENV still a correct pointer that I can use?

Can anyone tell me an elegant way to solve my problem?
Or any guidance is welcome, too!
Any explanation ... anything at all.
Thanks in advance!

Here's a sample of the JVM crash code:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9974cfc021, pid=7099, tid=140297087112960
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b24
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11.4
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x617021]  methodOopDesc::result_type() const+0x31
```

Comment: Is using JNA an option?  I gather it's much simpler, more like Python's ctypes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that `SIGINT` is an *asynchronous signal*; it can occur between any two machine instructions unless blocked.

This means that it is not safe to call anything but *async-safe functions* from your signal handler (and, if you want to be portable, you should not do anything but set `sig_atomic_t` variables). The JVM most certainly does not count as async-safe. Most likely, you are interrupting the JVM in the middle of some important code, and your method call is corrupting JVM state.

The approach usually used for handling `SIGINT` is to have a loop somewhere which checks a flag variable (of type `sig_atomic_t`). When you get a `SIGINT`, set the flag and return. The loop will come around and execute the rest of the handler in a safe, synchronous fashion.

In your case, you can just spawn off a Java thread which periodically calls a `checkForInterrupt` function that checks the aforementioned flag variable. `checkForInterrupt` returns the current flag status, and your thread can then choose to act on it.

The other option is to use a function like `pause`, `sigwait` or `sigsuspend` to suspend a thread until a signal is received. The thread then wakes up and processes the signal synchronously.

Comment: And the other (better) option is to use the self-pipe trick: write to a pipe in the signal handler, and `poll()` it in another thread. That way you won't be spinning needlessly as you would do with the flag approach.

Comment: AFAIK attribution for the self-pipe trick shoul go to DJB: http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html . Anyways, notice that in the Stack Exchange network _user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required_ .

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at 
http://javajiggle.com/2008/01/06/if-jni-based-application-is-crashing-check-signal-handling/
Seems like it might be the issue you are describing.

Edit: That link is old, this is the information that was in it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/signal-chaining.html

> To use libjsig.so, either link it with the application that
>   creates/embeds a HotSpot VM, for example:
>
> cc -L  -ljsig -ljvm java_application.c
>
> or use LD_PRELOAD environment variable, for example:
>
> export LD_PRELOAD=/libjsig.so; java_application (ksh)
>
> setenv LD_PRELOAD /libjsig.so; java_application (csh)
>
> The interposed signal()/sigset()/sigaction() return the saved signal
>   handlers, not the signal handlers installed by the Java HotSpot VM
>   which are seen by the OS.
>
> The signal-chaining facility was introduced to address Request for
>   Enhancement number 4381843.